# Light settings are black

Tags: light

Somehow I have managed to make it so that my model is not lit anymore.
I have attached a screenshot.
Can somebody tell me how to make it well-lit again?
Thank you.
[image]

When I press Z two times, the view is changed, but it is still not correct, I think:
[image]

Comment: You're in textured view.. Are you looking for solid view? (Try pressing Z twice)

Comment: Pressing Z twice improved it a little bit, but some walls are still black. I have updated my post accordingly.

Comment: Looks like the normals are also inverted. Try pressing `Ctrl N` with everything selected in order to recalculate them

Comment: Thank you. That did it. Do you perhaps want to make your comment the reply? And do you know how this could have happened?

Comment: Extruding in the wrong direction does it, it is common, don't worry :)

Comment: It happens from time to time, as there are many operations where blender must guess which way the normals should be facing (such as extruding). It's also possible you might have pressed `Ctrl Shift N` by accident.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I did not extrude anything in a special way, I think.

Comment: @gandalf3 I am relatively sure that I did not do this. Next time, I will record what I am doing.

Comment: @tmighty It is just which axis you do it on that changes it, i.e. the `-Z` instead of `+Z` axis